wordpress site messes up in github repository
i made a website using wordpress for portfolio, when i uploaded it as a repository in github it messed up everything nothing was in the right place.
 how it looks in local host
 how it looks in github
i first created the repository, changed the default branch to gh-pages, cloned it on the desktop app, commited the changes and pushed. then using simply static giving it the repository url, included wp-content and wp-content/upload and wp-includes folders, also set it to local-directory
i tried these steps several times but it's no use
https://github.com/iamgigin/interiordesign repository
https://iamgigin.github.io/interiordesign/ website link

look in the developer tools of your browser, there is lots of files missing, from plugins and theme.

Where is the backend hosted? GitHub Pages can only serve static content.

Notice that your deployment workflow tries to build this as a Jekyll page.
